# How is yield an enumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

I was toying around with `yield` and `IEnumerable` and I'm now curious why or how the following snippet works:

```
public class FakeList : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int one;
    private int two;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return one;
        yield return two;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now how does the compiler turn this:

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return one;
    yield return two;
}
```

into an `IEnumerator<int>`?

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When using `yield return`, the compiler generates an enumerator class for you. So the actual code which is used is much more complex than just two return statements. The compiler adds all necessary code to return an enumerator for you, which iterates over the results from the `yield return`.

---

This is the generated code from your `FakeList.GetEnumerator()`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class FakeList : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable
{
    private int one;
    private int two;

    [IteratorStateMachine(typeof(<GetEnumerator>d__2))]
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this.one;
        yield return this.two;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => 
        this.GetEnumerator();

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <GetEnumerator>d__2 : IEnumerator<int>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
    {
        private int <>1__state;
        private int <>2__current;
        public FakeList <>4__this;

        [DebuggerHidden]
        public <GetEnumerator>d__2(int <>1__state)
        {
            this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
        }

        private bool MoveNext()
        {
            switch (this.<>1__state)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.<>1__state = -1;
                    this.<>2__current = this.<>4__this.one;
                    this.<>1__state = 1;
                    return true;

                case 1:
                    this.<>1__state = -1;
                    this.<>2__current = this.<>4__this.two;
                    this.<>1__state = 2;
                    return true;

                case 2:
                    this.<>1__state = -1;
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        void IEnumerator.Reset()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
        }

        int IEnumerator<int>.Current =>
            this.<>2__current;

        object IEnumerator.Current =>
            this.<>2__current;
    }
}
```

Do you see the `<GetEnumerator>d__2` class? That is generated based on your two `yield return`s.

Answer (score 13):

When the compiler sees `yield return` or `yield break` it takes the function and coverts the logic it into a class that implements a state machine. An instance of this class is then returned when the method is called.

[C# In Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) has a section on what the code looks like.

Answer (score 6):

It's a generator.
I can't say how the compilator works behind, but when you do:

```
yield return x;
```

You will not leave the function like the classic return, instead you will return a value and then continue the execution of the function.

If I remember well, there is a little difference between a real enumerable and this one, if you don't use a method to transform your generator into a true enumerable (depending on what you are trying to accomplish) you can have some troubles.

Comment: Could you expand upon the difference? Because others are mentoning that the compiler generates a enumerable implementation

Comment: I will try to find it back.

Comment: did you find something?

Comment: I didn't succeed to find back the case where I got the issue. But by memory, it was about a reference problem. I couldn't enumerate twice on my enumerable generated. But when I did the test, it was fine. I still have a thing to try, it's with extension methods, the behavior could be different.

Comment: I really can't find it back. Since, I fixed it, I have no code to remember how I did that.